# Trigger event after KML Layer completely loaded

Tags: vector, layers, openlayers-2, events

I want to set the bounds of my map after a Vector (KML) Layer is loaded.

```
kmllayer.events.register('refresh', kmllayer, function(evt) {
    map.zoomToExtent(kmllayer.getDataExtent());
});
```

In the documentation there if something like the afterAdd function. But it does not work at all.

I am using version 2 of Openlayers.